# what is the simpliest way to organize txt document content into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to reorganize the content of the document to the dictionary but I am struggling a bit. Here is the code I tried but it does not execute in the right way. The content of the document is English dictionary I want to make the word a key and the meaning the value of the dictionary. Example: {'computer':'an electronic machine that is used for storing, organizing, and finding words, numbers, and pictures, for doing calculations, and for controlling other machines'}
I would appreciate any help. I am a beginner.

```
d = open(r'C:\assignemnt\document.txt', 'r')
ddict = {} 
for line in d:
    if line.strip():
        key, value = line.split(None, 1)
        ddict[key] = value.split()
print(ddict)
```

Comment: What exactly is the programming problem you encountered?

Comment: Could you give a sample of the contents of `document`?  Does it actually contain the meanings of the words?

Comment: As @samwise said, you should provide a few sample lines from the input document. However, looking at your code, you probably want to replace `None` with whatever character separates the key from the value on the line. It's also unclear why you then proceed to split the value again on the next line, but perhaps that's because there's multiple definitions - we can't tell without example data.

Comment: "Azygous (a.) Odd; having no fellow; not one of a pair; single; as, the azygous muscle of the uvula.

Azym (n.) Alt. of Azyme

Azyme (n.) Unleavened bread.

Azymic (a.) Azymous.

Azymite (n.) One who administered the Eucharist with unleavened bread; -- a name of reproach given by those of the Greek church to the Latins.

Azymous (a.) Unleavened; unfermented." This is a sample of the document

Comment: {'Azygous': ['(a.)', 'Odd;', 'having', 'no', 'fellow;', 'not', 'one', 'of', 'a', 'pair;', 'single;', 'as,', 'the', 'azygous', 'muscle', 'of', 'the', 'uvula.'], 'Azym': ['(n.)', 'Alt.', 'of', 'Azyme'], 'Azyme': ['(n.)', 'Unleavened', 'bread.'], 'Azymic': ['(a.)', 'Azymous.'], 'Azymite': ['(n.)', 'One', 'who', 'administered', 'the', 'Eucharist', 'with', 'unleavened', 'bread;', '--', 'a', 'name', 'of', 'reproach', 'given', 'by', 'those', 'of', 'the', 'Greek', 'church', 'to', 'the', 'Latins.'], 'Azymous': ['(a.)', 'Unleavened;', 'unfermented.']}

Comment: and this is the output and the problem is that I don't want the meaning of the word separated by commas. i want the meaning of the word executed as a single value of the key.